# How to sum total that refer to other dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to sum all combination from two DataFrames,

```
DataFrame A

         ColA    ColB   Sales
           1       A      10
           1       B      20
           1       C      100
           2       D      1000
           2       E      2000

DataFrame B
         ColA    ColB   
          1      A,B
          2      E
```

My Expect result for a DataFrame is

```
        ColA     ColB   TotalSales
         1       A,B     30
         2       E       2000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for a partially vectorised solution:

```
def summer(x):
    m1 = df_a['ColA'].eq(x['ColA'])
    m2 = df_a['ColB'].isin(x['ColB'].split(','))
    return df_a.loc[m1 & m2, 'Sales'].sum()

df_b['TotalSales'] = df_b.apply(summer, axis=1)

print(df_b)

   ColA ColB  TotalSales
0     1  A,B          30
1     2    E        2000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try of selecting dataframe A rows, which are in dataframe B ColB column and add the sales column of selected

```
#df
 ColA    ColB   Sales
   1       A      10
   1       B      20
   1       C      100
   2       D      1000
   2       E      2000


df.set_index('ColB',inplace=True)
#df
#       ColA    Sales
# ColB      
# A        1    10
# B        1    20
# C        1    100
# D        2    1000
# E        2    2000

#df1

 #ColA    ColB   
 # 1      A,B
 # 2      E

df1['TotalSales'] = df1.ColB.str.split(',').apply(lambda x: df.loc[x]['Sales'].sum() )
```

Out:

```
ColA    ColB    TotalSales
0   1   A,B 30
1   2   E   2000
```

Comment: thank for your help Naga, i tried your code but got "cannot do label indexing" error. do you know how to fix it please ?thanks

Comment: I checked it again, its working fine for the those dataframes A and B, in which line your getting the error @foy

Comment: it stated that i have   error   with "with these indexers [nan] of <class 'float'> but i  check them and they are not null

Comment: in which line is that error coming, can you provide a json or dictionary form of data in your question @foy

Comment: my bad, i have special character in it , so it can't run.  but now i have got another error that show "Keyerror : non of [ [ 'A','B' ]] are in the [index]

Comment: Please update the question with the json data of dataframes. i am not able to correlate to that error :-| .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184469/discussion-between-naga-kiran-and-foy).

Comment: This solution doesn't match on `ColA`, it only matches on `ColB`. Not sure if that's intentional. It also uses chained assignment, which is explicitly discouraged in the docs.