# How to create a dataframe from a column in another dataframe that concat by comma ','

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

i am wondering how to create a data frame that create from list of list and also transpose it

i have a data frame below

```
df :   ColA     ColB
       A,B,C    NA
       D,E      NA

df2 :  ColA    ColB   Sales
        A       B       10
        A       C       10
        B       C       10
        C       B       10
        C       A       2
        D       E       100
```

My Expected Result

```
df3 :  ColA    TotalSales
       A,B,C      42
       D,E        100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to your [previous related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53537144/9209546):

```
def summer(x):
    values = x.split(',')
    m1 = df2['ColA'].isin(values)
    m2 = df2['ColB'].isin(values)
    return df2.loc[m1 | m2, 'Sales'].sum()

df['TotalSales'] = df['ColA'].apply(summer)
```